Which overlapping is stronger 1s-2p or 2s-2p?
I tried to compare the bond strength of Sigma overlapping between the 1s-2p orbitals and 2s-2p orbitals. By using the analogy of 2s-2s and 3s-3s comparison, that is as the value of n increases bond strength decreases for same type of bond, the 1s-2p seems stronger but I wonder if this logic is applicable in this situation. It really would be a help if somone could confirm with a supporting explanation
